# Effect abstraction in Cats and parallel execution

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have the next code written using Cats IO that executes multiple actions in parallel (simplified):

```
import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    class ParallelExecIO {

        def exec: IO[List[String]] = {
            val foo = IO.shift *> IO("foo")
            val bar = IO.shift *> IO("bar")
            List(foo, bar).parSequence
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code using effect abstraction? What type evidences should be provided?

Sample:

```
class ParallelExecIO[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect /* ??? */] {

    def exec: F[List[String]] = {
        val foo = Async.shift[F](implicitly) *> "foo".pure[F]
        val bar = Async.shift[F](implicitly) *> "bar".pure[F]
        List(foo, bar).parSequence 
    }
}
```

> [error] value parSequence is not a member of List[F[String]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "0.10"
```

the error is

```
Error:(23, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter P: cats.Parallel[F,F]
      List(foo, bar).parSequence
```

So try

```
import cats.Parallel
import cats.effect.{Async, ConcurrentEffect}
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.language.higherKinds

class ParallelExecIO[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect, G[_]](implicit ev: Parallel[F, G]) {

  def exec: F[List[String]] = {
    val foo = Async.shift[F](implicitly) *> "foo".pure[F]
    val bar = Async.shift[F](implicitly) *> "bar".pure[F]
    List(foo, bar).parSequence
  }
}
```

<strike>Surely you can introduce `type Parallel[F[_]] = cats.Parallel[F, F]` and then this can be rewritten as `class ParallelExecIO[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect : Parallel] {...`</strike>

Comment: Thanks, rewritten class compiles although my IntelliJ marks `parSequence` red. But there is a problem with class instantiation.
```import IO._
  val pei = new ParallelExecIO[IO]()``` does not compile since new class requires evidence of type Parallel[IO, IO], but IO class provides implicit evidence `IO.ioParallel` of type `Parallel[IO, IO.Par]`. Should evidence type be fixed?
https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L723

Comment: Try `class ParallelExecIO[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect, G[_]](implicit ev: Parallel[F, G]) {...` `import IO._` `val pei = new ParallelExecIO`